# Detect closed communication in Spring Boot Web

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sockets

I have 2 spring-boot-starter-web services. Service A sends a request via Retrofit to service B. I have configured it to timeout after 10 seconds. Service A detects the timeout (SocketTimeoutException), but I have no way for service B to detect it. How can I verify that the socket is closed? I send a file via outputstream of httpServletResponse and it does not detect that it is closed. It looks like it sends the file to service A, when service A has already timed out.

```
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)){
            OutputStream out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(in,out); // copy from in to out
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // In AWS I get a "broken pipe" IOException. But, locally, I don't get any exception.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to check if a Socket is closed until the server tries to read/write from it. I workaround is handle this IOException's like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)   //(1)
public Object exceptionHandler(IOException e, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e), "Broken pipe")) {   //(2)
        return null;        //(2)   socket is closed, cannot return any response    
    } else {
        return new HttpEntity<>(e.getMessage());  //(3)
    }
}
```

This blog post [Spring - How to handle "IOException: Broken pipe"](https://mtyurt.net/post/spring-how-to-handle-ioexception-broken-pipe.html#) can help.

Comment: My problem is that locally, the server sending the response does not throw an IOException

Comment: When you mean "locally works", is running your two services locally and not be able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Exactly, when I run the two services locally I can't get the Broken pipe exception to come up.

Comment: Hm, okay, i think that because is running locally, the JVM don't really use network interfaces but pipes - i don't really know how to explain it